# Converting array of string into array of integer

Tags: hive, hiveql

Right now I'm having a performance issue with this query :

```
select userid from table_x inner join table_y on array_contains(split(table_y.userids,','),cast(table_x.userid as string))
```

The userids on y is represented as a string of numbers "123, 134, 156" which actually means three userids, namely 123,134 and 156. Table_x has a userid columns which details the personal information of each user. I want to select the userid which is contained in the userids column in table_y.

Am I right in assuming that the reason for the perforamance issue is because I have to convert the userids in table_y to array of string using split(table_y.userids,',') and use array_contains for string. If so, is there anyone who knows how to convert the string of userids into array of integer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are doing a Cartesian product join. Hive cannot join on `array_contains` - it is applied after hive generates all possible combinations.

To truly join, you need to use [`explode(split(table_y.userids,','))`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-explode) and then have a regular equality join:

```
select x.uid from (select cast(table_x.userid as string) as uid from table_x) x 
inner join 
(select explode(split(table_y.userids,',')) as uid from table_y) y on 
x.uid=y.uid;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation! This actually helps me to achieve a much faster performance